# ws: path is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, websocket

We are using [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws).

I start our WebSockets server like this:

```
const wsServer = require('ws').Server;

new wsServer({
  port: process.env.PORT
});
```

And clients connect like this:

```
new WebSocket('wss://irrelevant.herokuapp.com');
```

In the logs at Heroku I see something like this:

```
heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/:undefined" host=irrelevant.herokuapp.com request_id=b7f325f3-f1ab-4680-873c-f6b116e7ddcx fwd="54.166.51.7" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=2040923ms status=101 bytes=175
```

Where I am concerned about the `path="/:undefined"`, which to me looks wrong.
Should I set the path, if so on the server and the client?

Answer (score 1):

`wss` is for secure websocket.

As you have created `ws` server you need to change to

```
new WebSocket('ws://irrelevant.herokuapp.com');
```

Comment: What has that to do with the path? The server at Heroku can be connected to via `ws:` and `wss:`, but obviously I prefer SSL.

Comment: and the connection works. I am just concerned if I can optimize.

Comment: Heroku handles the SSL part, then routes the connection to my server, so every server inside Heroku is non SSL.

Comment: Ohh, then no idea with heroku